# Can humans of House Tharashk develop the Mark of Finding?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, eberron

After reading through Eberron: Rising from the Last War, I have noticed a conflicting statement regarding the Mark of Finding. On page 32, Half-Orcs and Dragonmarks, it states:

> The Mark of Finding appears among half-orcs of House Tharashk. Strangely, both orcs and humans associated with the house cannot develop this mark.

This directly conflicts with the information found on page 41 which goes into detail about the Mark of Finding:

> Alone among the dragonmarks, the Mark of Finding is carried by two races: humans and half­ orcs.
>
> [...]
>
> If your half-orc or human character has the Mark of Finding, the following traits replace the character's racial traits in the Player's Handbook, aside from age, alignment, size, and speed.

Additionally, there is nothing under the House Tharashk subheading about humans being unable to develop the Mark of Finding. Further, on page 37 under Dragonmarks and their Houses, both humans and half-orcs are listed as being associated with House Tharashk and the Mark of Finding.

Is this some kind of editorial/printing error or is there some piece of lore which allows both of these claims to be true?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## They can

This seems to be a revision problem in editing. It was at some point decided that humans of House Tharashk can't develop the mark, but it wasn't properly edited out everywhere. This, at least, seems to be the explanation D&D Beyond is going for on why humans in their editor can't take the mark.

Quoting [Stormknight on the D&D Beyond forums](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/bugs-support/27599-eberron-human-mark-of-finding):

> Mark of Finding is for Half-Orcs only.
>
> The first revision removed human from the house.

However, this was apparently not supposed to happen, as it's now on the fix list:

[Jeremy Crawford on twitter:](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1197387679928766465)

> The Mark of Finding game feature is correct. It works for both humans and half-orcs.

Previous iterations of Eberron in D&D did not have this limit, as elaborated by KRyan:

> 3.5e (the first to support Eberron) allowed humans, orcs, and half-orcs to get the Mark of Finding, and 4e allowed anyone to get any dragonmark

So it seems to be some sort of design decision that was made in the first revision of the new setting book for 5e that was poorly implemented throughout the book, and then later it was decided to revert the decision, but it was never properly fixed.